# how to find shared object files of a package which is installed by using sudo apt-get install command

Tags: object, ubuntu, path, shared, apt-get

I installed a package in ubuntu 12.04
now I have to set the path to the shared object files of that package in g++ to compile my C++ project.
I look at "/usr/local/lib" folder and do not find the so files of newly installed package.
Please tell me how I could find it.
Regards
Mahdi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dpkg -L <package>`

Fox example:

```
$ dpkg -L mc | grep mcdiff
/usr/bin/mcdiff
```